# how to negate conditional in Java?

Tags: java

I have this statement: (in Android)

```
if(marker.getTitle().indexOf("vous êtes ici")!=-1)
```

I want the contrary of it, any idea please?

I have tried:

```
if(marker.getTitle().indexOf("vous êtes ici")!=1)
```

but it does not work

Comment: It's simply `== -1`. Or, `!(!(!(x!=-1)))`, but the first is preferable :)

Comment: == -1 is the contrary of != -1

Comment: also try .contains(), this is java, not C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the not equals operator: !=

i.e.:

```
if (a != b)
{
    // Do something
}
```

The opposite is using the equals comparation (not inverted): ==

i.e.:

```
if (a == b)
{
    // Do something
}
```